# How to fill in missing values in one column based on a condition form another column using for loops in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
weather_train=pd.DataFrame({
'site_id':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
'air_temperature': [25,22,'NaN',28,'NaN',30,45,'NaN',50,'Nan',24]
})
```

- When `site_id` is 0, I need to calculate the mean `air_temperature` for `site_id` 0 and then use the mean to fill in the missing values for `air_temperature` in `site_id` 0.
- Then, when the `site_id` is 1, I need to calculate the mean `air_temperature` for site_id 1 and fill in the missing values for `air_temperature` in site_id 1.

Have to do the same process for `cloud_coverage`.

Can anyone help me write a for loop in pandas for this?

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops. Simply use `groupby().transform()` for inline mean aggregation enclosed in a conditional [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
weather_train['air_temperature'] = np.where(pd.isnull(weather_train['air_temperature']),
                                            weather_train.groupby(['site'])['air_temperature'].transform('mean'),    
                                            weather_train['air_temperature'])
```